# Magento not recognizing custom javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, magento

Ok, if this question has already been answered, I apologize, I have searched and not found a satisfactory answer that fits my situation.

Here is the situation:

I have a custom template file for displaying the products in a category, part of that list is the ability to add products directly to the cart with a specified quantity from the category page.  In order to accomplish this I wrote a function that re-writes the target line of the "Add to Cart" button, submits the request, then re-writes the button again back to it's original version (see code below).  The problem I'm running into is that every time the button is clicked right now I get an error in the debug panel stating that `customAddToCart is not defined`.  But if you look at the code for the product list template below you can see that the function is defined even before the list is generated (btw, I had it at the bottom of the page and was getting the same error).

If anyone can shed some light on why the javascript function would be undefined when it's being included on the same page as the list...I could sure use some help.

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
*/
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function customAddToCart( product_id, url ){
        var qty = document.getElementById('qty_input_'+product_id).value;
        document.getElementById('addtocartbutton_'+product_id).setAttribute('onclick', "setLocation(" + url + "/qty/" + qty ")");
        document.getElementById('addtocartbutton_'+product_id).click(); return false;
        document.getElementById('addtocartbutton_'+product_id).setAttribute('onclick', "customAddToCart(" + product_id + ", " + url + ")");
    }
</script>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(230, null); ?>" width="230" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>                    
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                             <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="add-to-cart-options">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if( !($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product) || $_product->isGrouped() )){ ?>
                        <label for="qty_input">Quantity: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="spinner qty-input" name="qty_input" id="qty_input_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" />
                        <?php /*<p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p> */ ?>
                        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="javascript:customAddToCart(<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <button type="button" class="button" id="addtocartbutton_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>    
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

<?php else: ?>
```

As you can see, the function is clearly defined at the top of the page, so why this button

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="javascript:customAddToCart(<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
```

results in a message in the console saying that `customAddToCart is not defined` I'm not sure.

Comment: Try scoping javascript in `CDATA`.. if you don't know what I mean then refer base/default/template files where the script will be scoped with comments of CDATA.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, I think it was a combination of what you recommended and wbaaron suggested below, but I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an error about an "Unexpected string"? The concatenation in the second line of your function is missing its last plus sign.

Update

```
"/qty/" + qty ")"
```

to

```
"/qty/" + qty + ")"
```

and refresh.